# Powershell remotely executed process is without window

Tags: powershell, process, command

Got here strange issue , when i run remote a process with PowerShell - it is hidden. Even notepad - runs without a window.
I am running it with the same user i login to check , with all the rights. I tried different ways to execute - VS , PSexec - the same thing everywhere. I added -windowstyle normal as argument to start-process - does not affect , also i tried & command - same thing...

Comment: It does not interact with a users desktop. There is nothing to see.

Comment: I think i did not describe it correctly - i am running a process on remote machine with powershell command , like " start-process -filepath "notepad.exe" -windowstyle normal " but still it is hidden and without a window. It runs under credentials of logged in user , so he should be able to see that.

Comment: I think i am getting what you said. Ok , is there a way to start a program using powershell so it will interact and user will see window of the application ?

Comment: If you use PSRemoting then it will never display on the desktop. PSexec on the other hand has a flag you can specify to start a application in the console session.